# lex - unrecognized rule - using regex

Tags: c, regex, parsing, lex

I am new to working with lex and just wanted to try and see whether I could try making a file that would locate comments in a C file using regular expressions.

```
%%

(/\*([^*]|[^]|(\*+([^*/]|[^])))*\*+/)|(//.*){   
    return 5;
}
.   ;

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
    return1;
}
```

So the idea here would be that everytime a comment is located, it will "return 5", otherwise, nothing happens.

The problem is, the  regular expression is not being recognized and i'm met with the error:

line 3: unrecognized rule
line 3: unrecognized rule
line 3: unrecognized rule
line 3: unrecognized rule
...etc

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Great.  What actually *does* happen?

Comment: an error: :3 :unrecognized rule, aka the regular expression is not being recognized (editing this into the main question --woops)

Comment: Your rule should be separated from its action by whitespace.  Also, I recommend separate rules for matching the two varieties of comments.

Comment: Note, too, that the pattern fragment `[^*]|[^]` is equivalent to just `[^*]`, and the fragment `[^*/]|[^]` is equivalent to `[^*/]`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Not quite. `[^]` is an unterminated character class (not just in flex; in posix, too.)

Comment: alright, but do you think that the unrecognized rule could also stem from any incompatible regex statements? I was actually intending to have the [\r\n] used in place of the [^] but wasn't sure whether it would be accepted

Comment: @Shno: there's nothing wrong with using `[\r\n]` but it would be pointless, since both of those characters are already part of `[^*]` (`.` doesn't match `\n`, but that's specific to `.`; `\n` is not artificially removed from character classes.)

Answer (score 1):

In (f)lex regular expressions, as in standard Posix regexes, you can include <kbd>]</kbd> in a character class as the *first* character in the class. (That's true whether or not you use a positive (`[...]`) or negative (`[^...]`) character class.)

So the first`[^]` starts a character class, which is then terminated by the next `]`, and the next one is unterminated. It's not clear to me what you expected `[^]` to mean, so I can't offer an alternative suggestion.

Also, you need a space before the action, in order to define the end of the regular expression.

Comment: thank you for taking the time, (and john too) i have found that the [^] class was poorly used by me so I simply removed it in this case, I also realized that I needed to escape the '/' in the regex in order for it to be read as I didn't realize that it was an actual operation in lex according to: http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno//CS447/Lectures/Lexical.html/node11.html, these two changes helped fix my problem up nicely